# Play Framework Ebean strange behavior when running on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, playframework, ebean

I've recently developed a web application in Play Framework using java template on Mac OSX.But now I had to run the same application on Windows.

When running on Mac, everything looks good and functional. But a weird behavior occurs when running on Windows when loading a Model using `Model.Finder` and `@ManyToOne` annotation.

Example of my Models:

models/Ticket.java

```
@Entity
public class Ticket extends Model {

    ...

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_type", referencedColumnName="id_type")
    public TicketType type;

    public static Model.Finder<Integer, Ticket> find = new Model.Finder<Integer,Ticket>(Integer.class, Ticket.class);
}
```

models/TicketType.java

```
@Entity
public class TicketType extends Model {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public Integer id_type;

...

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "type")
public Ticket ticket;

...
}
```

So, this is the output (Json) of one register in my DB when running on Mac OSX:

```
{
"id_ticket":10,
"type":{
    "id_type":4,
    "nm_description":"Ticket Type 1",
    "st_active":true,
    "vl_price":16.0,
    "ticket":null
    }
}
```

And the Json generated with the same method, when running on Windows:

```
{
"id_ticket":10,
"type":{
    "id_type":4,
    "nm_description":null,
    "st_active":false,
    "vl_price":null,
    "ticket":null
    }
}
```

Only the field `id_type` is correct.

I've already tried to recompile the project and change machines, but none of this worked so far.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue. For some reason, I didn't notice I was copying `target` , `project/target` and `project/project` folder. Just deleted these folders and recompiled everything.